# How should I design my django models for team, player and match objects?

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure how to ask this question ? First let me explain i have `Team` and `Player` models.

```
class team()
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100) // name quato something like this

class player(models.Model) 
        point = models.IntegerField()
        assist = models.IntegerField() 
        rebound = models.IntegerField() //something like this 
        team = models.ForeignKey(team)
```

I need a `Match` model and players ( point,assist,rebound ) for that match; how do I create a model to represent it?

Comment: Please don't use profanity in your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this an exercise/homework with simplifying assumptions, or are you modelling a real-world application?  For example, players may change teams over time: how will you model it?  For simplicity, let us assume that players don't change teams.  I would model your case as follows:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # other attributes that do not change over time

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    # other attributes that do not change over time

class Match(models.Model):
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    # other non-redundant attributes

class PlayerMatch(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match)

    points = models.IntegerField()
    assists = models.IntegerField()
    rebounds = models.IntegerField()
```

The important part here is that statistics are kept in `PlayerMatch` only.  You don't have to repeat them in `Player` or in `Match`, that would be [redundant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_redundancy).  Instead, statistics for a match or for a player can be calculated given these data structures.

Comment: Thank you this was what i was looking for. But match is between teams not players how can i represent this? I understand i can add all team members to the match but it is too redundant. Hope you will reply.

Comment: @Bolo could you do this with a 'through' relationship?

Comment: @Private I didn't know about `through` before, but it seems to be the right tool to use here.  Perhaps you could write an answer which uses `through`?  I'd be glad to upvote it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
class StatisticsBase(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    points = models.IntegerField()   # plural form reads easier here
    assists = models.IntegerField()  # at least in English
    rebounds = models.IntegerField()


class Player(StatisticsBase):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Match(StatisticsBase):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)  # you should capitalize class names
    # any additional fields
```